# Invalid token 'in' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, token

```
class operation
{
    public void add(int val1 , int val2)
    {
        int result;
        result= val1+ val2;
        return  result;
    }
}

class view : operation
{
    public override in  add(int val1 , int val2)
    {   
        int result;
        result = val1+val2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
Invalid token 'in' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

How can I remove this error from above code?

Comment: I'm guessing this is C++, so I've added it as a tag.

Comment: Actually, now I'm not so sure.  This isn't valid C++.  What language is this?

Comment: @Oli: `override` is a `C#` construct.

Comment: @Mohammad: what is that `in` thing supposed to mean? Did you mean `int`?

Comment: Normally I try to be nice, but honestly this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in` is a reserved keyword in C#. You probably want:

```
public override int add(int val1, int val2)
```

Also in order to be able to override some method in a derived class this method must be virtual in the base class:

```
public class operation
{
    public virtual int add(int val1, int val2)
    {
        int result;
        result = val1 + val2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the `operation` base class you have declared the `add` method with no return type and yet you are trying to return an integer.

Also there's no point in overriding a base method just to repeat the same code. You could simply invoke the base method in the overriden method:

```
public class view : operation
{
    public override int add(int val1, int val2)
    {
        return base.add(val1, val2);
    }
}
```

or simply:

```
public class view : operation
{
}
```

which would be equivalent because you are not modifying anything in this method.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't `in` be `int`?  And shouldn't the first `add` return `int` rather than `void`?